# Pyspark 2.4 Issue faced while passing properties file in spark submit

Tags: mysql, pyspark, properties-file, spark-submit

I have a pyspark program which connects to MySQL db successfully and reads a table. Now, I am trying to pass the database credentials from a properties file, instead of embedding them in the code, but not able to make it work.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import * 

#spark-submit –packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.13 workWithMySQL.py
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(“MySQL connection”).getOrCreate()

#create spart context from spark session
sc = spark.sparkContext

#read from mysql

#configuration details
hostname=”localhost”
jdbcport=3306
dbname=”TEST”
username=”kanchan@localhost”
password=”password”
mysql_url = “jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}?user={3}&password={4}”.format(hostname,jdbcport,dbname,username,password)
mysql_driver = “com.mysql.jdbc.Driver”
query = “(select * from cats) t1_alias”
df4 = spark.read.format(“jdbc”).options(driver=mysql_driver,url=mysql_url, dbtable=query).load()
df4.show()
```

Now, I have created a properties file jdbc.properties at `$SPARK_HOME/conf`

```
spark.mysql.user kanchan@localhost
spark.mysql.password password
```

And add it in spark-submit call

```
spark-submit –packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.13 --files $SPARK_HOME/conf/jdbc.properties workWithMySQL.py
```

replaced the assignments:

```
username=sc.getConf.getOption("spark.mysql.user")
password=sc.getConf.getOption("spark.mysql.user")
```

when run. it throws an error saying the function has no attribute as get option. I could not locate the appropriate documentation for it. Can anyone help?

Further, is it possible to encrypt the credentials or ensure data security by any other means?

Comment: please ask only one question per post, otherwise it is confusing when other people search for similar topics.

Comment: Sure, I would follow the convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getOption` should be replace with the method `get`.

```
username=sc.getConf().get("spark.mysql.user")
```

Comment: Thank you Steven. The issue was resolved after I made the correction, plus replaced the "--files" with "--properties-file" in the spark-submit call. Is there a better way to pass the credentials in such cases?

Comment: it depends a lot on your system. For example, you could use a keyvault. or reference your spark machine in a white list from your db.

Comment: @kanchantewary if the issue is solved, you can accept the answer